# Android Studio Gradle Error Error:Cause: net.rubygrapefruit.platform.internal.jni.PosixProcessFunctions.getPid()I

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I am using android studio and after my most recent launch of the IDE i get a gradle error when I try to run the project. This is the error.

Error:Cause: net.rubygrapefruit.platform.internal.jni.PosixProcessFunctions.getPid()I

I have made no changes from my code as of the last run, and for some reason this is now happening. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Which version of Gradle are using? Have you tried clearing the contents of the ~/.gradle/native folder?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I restarted the IDE and it appears to work now. Still no idea as to the cause of the problem, however a quick restart seemed to work for now.

Answer (score 1):

For me, I just modify **gradle-wrapper.properies** file.

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.2.1-all.zip
```

=>   `distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-3.3-all.zip`

Answer (score 0):

After update/install new plugin in IntelliJ sometimes Gradle plugin crushes. Just do in IntelliJ Flie -> Invalidate caches/Restart.

Answer (score 0):

This error does sometimes seem to pop up when there is a SDK update in Android Studio. To fix this, go to the `gradle-wrapper.properties` file, and update the `distributionUrl` as such:

1. Go to the following URL: https://services.gradle.org/distributions/
2. Check the latest version of the gradle distributable. Look at the top most files for the latest version number. At the time of writing this answer, 8.6 is the latest version.
3. Go back to your `gradle-wrapper.properties` file and edit the `distributionUrl` by replacing the existing version with the latest version that you found in step 2. Here is an example:

*Old version*: `distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-8.2-bin.zip` 
*Replace with*:
`distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-8.6-bin.zip`

4. Sync gradle after doing the changes. Your IDE should prompt you automatically to do so.