# Android Studio - Failed to complete Gradle execution - getPid()

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-studio-2.0

I just installed Android Studio, I installed the recommended packages from the SDK Manager, now I am trying to build a sample app. I got this error message:

```
Failed to complete Gradle execution:
Cause:
net.rubygrapefruit.platform.internal.jni.PosixProcessFunctions.getPid()
```

Any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26985536/android-studio-gradle-error-errorcause-net-rubygrapefruit-platform-internal-jn

Comment: I restarted my IDE and it works. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got same issue, I restarted IDE. It started working fine after that.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I have updated the version of the Gradle Wrapper to the latest.

Open the file gradle-wrapper.properties.

Change the url of *distributionUrl*.

Example:

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-3.2.1-bin.zip
```

Refresh the Gragle project and you should be good to go.